# Help with Plotting Logscale?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm trying to plot the time complexity of some sorting algorithms using a log scale. I'm fetching the data from a text file `insertion.dat` which contains the following information:

```
x y
0 0
10 0.002
100 0.019
1000 1.636
5000 42.735
10000 167.950
```

and I'm using the following code to try implement it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
width=15cm,
height=7cm,
axis x line=center,
axis y line=center,
ytick={0,10,100,1000},
xtick={0,10, 1000, 5000,10000},
ymode=log, xmode=log,
xlabel={\texttt{L}},
ylabel={Time (ms)},
xlabel style={right},
ylabel style={above},
xmin=0,
xmax=15000,
ymin=0,
ymax=2000]
\addplot[smooth,red,thick] table[y expr=\thisrow{y}/0.95] {insertion.dat};      
\end{axis}         
\end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

But the result I get is:

[image]

What's up with the axes? How can I fix this?

Comment: 0,0 is a bit outside the range of a logscale plot... ;-)

Comment: @Rmano Oh yeah, of course! But when I set xmin and ymin equal to 10 and remove (0,0) I still get the space between the axes.

Comment: The `axis [xy] line` probably get confused by the log scale. Why don't you use `\begin{logaxis}` to start with?

Comment: I played around with it and I managed to smarten it up. All I need to do is to position the x-axis more to the left so that it touches the y-axis line. Do you know how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main mistake is that you use `axis y line=center` which implies that the axis should go through `0`, or in the case of a log axis through `1`. When you change this to `axis y line=left` and at least the `xmin` value, you should get the desired result. But then the `ylabel` is positioned left in the middle (again). This can be modified using the `ylabel style` key.

```
\begin{filecontents}{insertion.dat}
    x y
    10 0.002
    100 0.019
    1000 1.636
    5000 42.735
    10000 167.950
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            xmode=log,
            ymode=log,
            %
            width=15cm,
            height=7cm,
            axis x line=center,
            axis y line=left,   % <-- `center' confuses PGFPlots on a log axis
            xmin=5,
            xmax=15000,
            ymin=1e-3,
            ymax=2000,
            xlabel={\texttt{L}},
            ylabel={Time (ms)},
            xlabel style={right},
            ylabel style={
                at={(rel axis cs:0,1)},
                rotate=-90,
                anchor=south,
            },
        ]
            \addplot [smooth,red,thick,mark=*]
                table [y expr=\thisrow{y}/0.95] {insertion.dat};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]